# ExceptionInInitializerError in Karaf 3.0.2 deploying my war

Tags: war, karaf

Good Day,

Im trying to deploy my war file in Karaf 3.0.2, my servlet is trying to read some S3 files, but I'm getting this error on Instantiating the AmazonS3Client

```
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();

2015-01-09 13:04:02,205 | INFO  | pool-7-thread-1  | S3Properties                     | 75 - my-domain - 3.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Loading file from S3: my-web.properties
2015-01-09 13:04:02,241 | WARN  | pool-7-thread-1  | AbstractLifeCycle                | 91 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.15.v20140411 | FAILED MyPerfFilter: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:134)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:95)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:42)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:379)
```

I thought it was a problem on my static block but I'm thinking it's not, as I have tried to create a simplehelloworld servlet that calls the same class that has this static block and it worked reading the S3 files

```
static {
    System.out.println("test 1");
    instance = new MyProperties();
    try {
        System.out.println("test 2");
        instance.load(PROPS_FILENAME);
        reloadable = true;
        System.out.println("test 3");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            System.out.println("test 3");
            // try to load the file from the classpath instead
            instance.load(MyProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + PROPS_FILENAME));
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            logger.error("Exception caught when loading properties: {}", PROPS_FILENAME, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: thanks Scott for formatting it

Comment: I am having the same issue, so if anyone figures out the answer would love to know!

Comment: It's a SMX aws-java-sdk issue, there is a missing config file that is not included in the bundle
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SMX4-1921